# Why can I not copy and paste the FontAwesome icon fa-home?

Tags: font-awesome, copy-paste

I have [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) version 4.6.3 installed locally. Copying and pasting icons, either from [cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) or [Copy & Paste](https://fontawesome.veliovgroup.com/design.html), generally works in any text editor (tested with `vim` and `libreoffice`). Some, however, do not work, like the **home** icon (`fa-home` [`&#xf015;`]).

I think I face this very problem as described at this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/3y7bnf/copypasting_fontawesome_icon_does_not_work/). As suggested in some comment, in this reddit post, I open `FontAwesome` using `gucharmap`. Right clicking on it shows only the *home* icon, no more. Double clicking on it, however, does not paste it below in the `Text to copy:` field, as it works with most of the icons.

Why is this so?